# Center an unordered list (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to center a ul with two li's inside. However I cannot get it work. Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="ul-home">           
        <li id="li-home">
            <a id="a-home" href="search.php">Click here to search for a free computer room</a>
        </li>   
        <li id="li-home">
            <a id="a-home" href="my_bookings.php">Click here to search through your bookings</a>
        </li>   
</ul>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#ul-home
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:70%;
  text-align:center;
}

#li-home
{
  display: inline;
}

#a-home:link, #a-home:visited
{
      color:#FFF;
      background-color:#F0984A;
      padding:20px;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-weight:bold;
}

#a-home:hover, #a-home:active
{
  background-color:#D6721A;
}

#a-home
{
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The two links are to the left of the center, by about 200px. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your `ul` is wider than the colored area, its in the middle with the childs aligning to the left...this gives the impression that `ul` is not in the middle =>  [**see this here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sps7X/)

**To solve :**

- either
  add `text-align:center;` to `#ul-home` **=>**  [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sps7X/1/)

or

- reduce the `ul` width **=>**  [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sps7X/3/)  (*not recommended though*)

**EDIT**

You have `padding-right:20px;` set at `#li-home` this will always push content to left =>  [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sps7X/4/)

Remove it and you are in perfect center =>  [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sps7X/5/)

Comment: I did this and it's still to the left of the center.

Comment: just added the demo from my end, can u show your the fiddle??

Comment: @user2397282 : found mistake in your code, please check the **edit** :)

Comment: It's now slightly to the right. Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qf2J7/, although the width on #a-home doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: you want like this?? => http://jsfiddle.net/Qf2J7/1/

Comment: @user2397282 : please see the **edit** in my answer too!!

Comment: Your edit seems to work well, but when I copy it and put it into my CSS, it doesn't seem to work..?

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/38Wa8/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46829/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-user2397282)

Comment: @user2397282 : your last fiddle is quite in center, m waiting to chat with u, where u can explain me better about what u want..:p

Comment: @user2397282 : since u r a difficult person to reach....may i ask u to drop a comment if your problem is still not solved or mark the answer as accepted to close the question!! :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay! I managed to get it to work by just putting the two links inside a div, and centering that. For some reason, the ul just wasn't working on my website. Nonetheless, thank you for your help!!

Comment: @user2397282 : if u have site live on some url, show it else...provide a screen-shot...m pretty sure we can work it out!! :)

Answer (score 1):

your #ul-home needs the css instruction

```
padding-left: 0;
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h7X7S/2/

Comment: To understand the problem and solve this, i used the inspector of Chrome..i suggest you to use it, it helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center` to `#ul-home`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2pR/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` to your `ul`, also you might want to remove default padding from `ul`
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v2kE/)

Answer (score 0):

to the parent div of UL try to add `text-align:center`

and for the UL try to add `display:inline-block`